# Shortcode for buddypress in divi wordpress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using wordpress divi theme and I installed buddypress for social feed.But I want to get a short code for activity stream page as I want to display it to a section on my main page.Help Please.Urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can achieve that by using [BuddyPress Activity shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-activity-shortcode/) plugin. It allows you to insert BuddyPress activity stream on any page/post using shortcode.